# Strange nocturnal animal sounds in Massachusetts

Tags: animals, massachusetts

My husband and I were woken last night by animal sounds we've never heard before.  We live in MA on the border of NH by wetlands.  It sounded like a group of animals, at least 3.   Their sound started with a clicking or tapping noise, then into something garbled, and ended with a type of cooing.  Because of the cooing, we assumed they were a type of bird.  Any ideas?

Comment: This may be the result of more than one type of animal.  Don't underestimate the range of sounds frogs can make.  They could possibly explain all but the cooing sound.  I've heard porcupines make something like a cooing sound, especially when young are around, but there are many other possibilities.  A recording would help a lot.

Comment: I don't really know US birds, but many birds will impersonate sounds they hear, UK blackbirds for example do this or the famous [Lyre bird](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjE0Kdfos4Y). So it could be one of these species. Without more info though I feel this may be hard to answer

Comment: I live in Mass too, though not as far North as you. Can you add a few details, like the name of your town? Are you on the ocean or is it inland wetlands? Was the noise close to home or in the water? Do you have trees? If you have bird feeders were any knocked down? Do you see any tracks? Was it loud, for instance louder than chipmunk chirps? Can you describe the pitch, like was the garbled something higher or lower than the cooing? It's breeding season for a lot of things in our area. so the coo could be a mating call on land, air or water. It also could be youngsters.

Comment: It's interesting that you've lived here a while and never heard it. It could be one or a group of things migrating through. Would you post a picture of the general area? Please add your details into your question rather than a comment. Just press the grey edit word on the bottom of the question. It will open up and you can add anything you can think of that might help us narrow this down. Thanks, and welcome to the site!